# Scala USING of USING

Tags: scala, using, ioexception, file-read

I have csv with data like this:

```
1;57840
2;57840
3;57834
...
```

And simple scala code to read this data into Seq of Tuple2[Int,Int]

Code:

```
case class Tick(Data : Tuple2[Int,Int]) {
  val tNum : Int = Data._1
  val tVal : Int = Data._2
}

case class TicksDs(Data : Seq[Tick]) {
  def size : Int = Data.size
}

class scvReader(CsvPath : String){

  def using[A <: { def close(): Unit }, TicksDs](param: A)(f: A => TicksDs): TicksDs =
    try {
      f(param)
    } finally {
      //param.close()
    }

  def readTicks : TicksDs = {
    using(io.Source.fromFile(CsvPath)) { source =>
       TicksDs(source.getLines.map{oneLine => (oneLine.split(";")(0).toInt-1,
                                               oneLine.split(";")(1).toInt)}.toSeq.map(x => Tick(x._1,x._2)))
    }
  }

}

object CurryingFuncs extends App {
  val ticks : TicksDs = new scvReader("data/simple.csv").readTicks
  println("ticks.size="+ticks.size+" ticks(Class): "+ticks.getClass.getName)
  for (tick <- ticks.Data) {
    println(tick.tNum+" "+tick.tVal+" "+tick.getClass.getName)
  }
}
```

It's everything fine and this return me output:

```
ticks.size=50 ticks(Class): TicksDs
0 57840 Tick
1 57840 Tick
2 57834 Tick
3 57831 Tick
...
```

But when I uncomment line  //param.close() it raise error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
...
...
```

Where is mistake and how fix it? Thanks.

Fix (thanks to [jwvh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh)):

```
    ...
      def using[A <: { def close(): Unit }, B](param: A)(f: A => B): B =
        try f(param)
         finally param.close()
    ...

   ...
        using(io.Source.fromFile(CsvPath)) { source =>
           TicksDs(source.getLines.map{oneLine => (oneLine.split(";")(0).toInt-1,
                                                   oneLine.split(";")(1).toInt)}.toList.map(x => Tick(x._1,x._2))) //was .toSeq now .toList
        }
```

Comment: As a style tip, I'd ditch the structural type for close, and replace it with Closeable.

Comment: Thanks, but could you give me little bit more information? I am newbie in scala.

Comment: I'm trying man, but I don't understand the problem either, If I come up with a solution I'll post an answer. I'm currently trying to decompile the classes to get a hint.

Comment: I'm giving up, but I'd still love to see an answer.

Comment: To answer the question explicitly about the structural type, it uses reflection and is relatively slow for little benefit in this situation. Change it to `def using[A <: AutoCloseable, TicksDs]` as Source https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/io/Source.html extends Closeable and Closeable extends AutoCloseable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you're closing the source before it is emptied.

This, `source.getLines`, produces an `Iterator[String]` which is evaluated lazily, and the `toSeq` later that same line doesn't change it. If you use `toList` instead then that will force evaluation of the complete file contents before the `close()`.

Also, you don't need `TicksDs` as a type parameter to `using()`. It's not serving any purpose.

```
def using[A <: {def close(): Unit}]( . . .
```

Comment: Damn, I should have tried stepping through it before jumping all the way to decompiled code. Thanks you put me out of my misery.

Comment: @AlekseyYakushev If this post solved your problem, SO recommends upvoting and accepting it as the solution, it's the best way of saying thanks.